# Google Sheets Script only working on one file

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-forms

I am trying to have the google forms on our website auto-notify us when a user completes the form and then return the data that they entered in a concise email. I do not like the way google notifies you it simply links to you the form to view the response. I searched online and found this code:

```
function sendFormByEmailPrayer(e) 
{    
  // Remember to replace XYZ with your own email address
  var email = "admin@communionchapelefca.org"; 

  // Optional but change the following variable
  // to have a custom subject for Google Docs emails
  var subject = "Prayer Form Form Submitted";  

  // The variable e holds all the form values in an array.
  // Loop through the array and append values to the body.

  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var headers = s.getRange(1,1,1,s.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
  var urlToDoc = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getUrl();
  var body = "";
  body = body + "Link to Document: " + urlToDoc;

  var message = body + "\n\n" + "";

  // Credit to Henrique Abreu for fixing the sort order

  for(var i in headers)
    message += headers[i] + ' = '+ e.namedValues[headers[i]].toString() + "\n\n"; 

  // This is the MailApp service of Google Apps Script
  // that sends the email. You can also use GmailApp here.

  MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, message); 

  // Watch the following video for details
  // http://youtu.be/z6klwUxRwQI

  // By Amit Agarwal - www.labnol.org
}
```

On Form Submit screenshot:
[image]

It works great on my one form, but when I copied and pasted this working code to our other 6 forms, it does not work at all. How do I get this to work across our 7 forms? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you install an "On Form Submit" trigger in the other scripts?  In the code editor, you need to click on the "Resources" menu, and choose "Current Project Triggers", and then add a new trigger, and choose the function name.  I don't see anything in the code that is specific to one Google Spreadsheet or Form.  If the code works in one place, and doesn't work in another place, and the code is generic, it can't be the script itself.

Comment: Yes the On Form Submit is there for all other scripts. Screenshot posted in OP.

Yes, that's why I am perplexed. The code is so generic that it can't be the script but I am at a loss as to what's causing it.

Answer (score 0):

Well I found a better solution than the code presented above. If you use the new Google Forms you can add an "add-on" (YourForm-->Three Dots in top right-->Add-ons).

From there look for ["Simply Send"](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/simply-send/dfpmmnbflloldgmcbmpcgiklcckibeff?utm_source=permalink) it will auto email a response with headers. Took me about 5 seconds to setup each of my forms.